# How to apply style to all Buttons but not to ImageButtons?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, imagebutton, android-styles

I need to apply a background color to all the buttons in my application, so I added this to styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- button styles -->
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/button_color</item> <!-- below api 21 -->
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/button_color</item> <!-- above api 21 -->
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonColor</item>
</style>

<style name="ButtonColor" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/font</item>
</style>
```

It worked perfectly, when I add a button in XML, the button has automatically the colors I set in styles.xml

The problem is that when I add a ImageButton, the ImageButton is getting also those colors, and I don't want that. The problem is specifically with `colorButtonNormal`, which applyes the background color to the ImageButton also and I don't want that. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There is a `Widget.Material.ImageButton`. Have you tried overriding the attribute and setting this to `android:imageButtonStyle`?

Answer (score 2):

The default style used by the `ImageButton` (in your case `AppCompatImageButton`) is defined in the app theme by the attr:

```
<item name="imageButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton</item>
```

In this style the background attribute `<item name="background">@drawable/btn_default_material</item>` is tinted with the `android:tint="?attr/colorButtonNormal"`.

You can use a custom style starting from `btn_default_material` for the `ImageButton` or you can override the color in the layout.
Something like:

```
<ImageButton  
     android:theme="@style/MyImageButtonTheme"/>
```

with something like:

```
  <style name="MyImageButtonTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"> 
      <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/my_color</item> 
 </style>
```

Also evaluate to migrate to Material Components and the `MaterialButton`.
In this case it is very simple to override the color just using the styles:

```
  <style name="MyButtonTheme" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ButtonStylePrimaryColor</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ButtonStylePrimaryColor">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by applying different style for defferent views

Let's say i have three style with defferent color combination and i wish to apply bigButtonTheme style for all big button

Then

i add this line on all big button  `android:theme="@style/bigButtonTheme">`

Rest button or other vewis will remain unchanged.
You can also copy other properties of a style like global themes font background color by deffineing as parents theme

```
<style name="ButtonColor" parent="@style/GlobelStyleOfApp"/>
```